# Angularjs - ng-submit not working in form

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to submit a simple form using ng-submit but the button not working as well as it's not clickable, It's working on Firefox but the cursor still not changing when it's on the button and not working on Chrome.

## HTML

```
<form novalidate name="newTripForm" ng-submit="vm.addTrip()">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Trip Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"  ng-model="vm.newTrip.name"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="submit" value="Add"/>
      </div>  
</form>
```

## JavaScript

```
 vm.addTrip = function ()
    {
        alert(vm.newTrip.name);
    };
```

Comment: you have `ng-submit` on input and form, remove one on the input

Comment: that's also not working see my edited post.

Comment: Probably something to do with your controller. if you have a scope variable $scope.addTrip, then you should be able to use addTrip on the ng-submit

Comment: Is the alert method being executed. Pass a string in the alert method  to check if ng-submit is working..

Comment: test your syntax or your function by putting `ng-click="vm.addTrip()"` on input, if it doesn't fire, then you have something wrong in your controller

Comment: it's working on firefox but the cursor not changing when it's the button

Comment: Consider accepting an answer or write your own if you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<form novalidate name="newTripForm" ng-submit="vm.addTrip()">
  <div class="form-group" ng-init="vm.newTrip.name = '';">
      <label for="name">Trip Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"  ng-model="vm.newTrip.name" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
       <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="submit" value="Add"/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on and [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit), you can have two submits on your form.

I created a quick sample based of what is on the docs and your example.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("test", []);
  
  var TestController = function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.newTrip = {
      name: ""
    };
    vm.addTrip = function() {
      // Some code
      console.log("Added " + vm.newTrip.name + " to database!");
      vm.newTrip.name = "";
    }
  }

  app.controller("TestController", [TestController]);
})();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestController as vm">
    <form novalidate name="newTripForm" ng-submit="vm.addTrip()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Trip Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" ng-model="vm.newTrip.name" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="submit" value="Add" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this remove the form

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Trip Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"  ng-model="vm.newTrip.name"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <button ng-click="addTrip()"></button>
      </div>
```